# Centering not working on pdf/tikz plot!

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have looked at other posts regarding how to center a "figure." To be clear, I want to center the plot in the center of the document.

I have followed the advice of many to use "\centering." However, I placed it in several locations (the one shown is one among them), and it has not centered the plot. What am I doing wrong?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax = 4, ymax = 4, samples = 50]
   \centering
   \addplot[black, smooth,domain=0:1] {sqrt(1 - 4*(x - 1/2)^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, \centering needs to go before \begin{tikzpicture}

Comment: Perfect. Thank you marmot. I did not want to keep pestering you with questions. :P

Comment: @marmot Do you want to add an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments